# Hoisting in ES6 with respect to `let` and block scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I run the following code written using ES6 `let`:

```js
function doSmth(){
  age=27;
}
let age;
doSmth();
console.log(age);
```

I get the output correctly as 27.

Now I am a bit confused as to how this works. Specifically, I have read is that `let` has a block scope.

So, how is it that `let age`, which is declared outside the function `doSmth`, is the same variable inside the function `doSmth`? 
Is that something to do with global scope, but if yes, then what role does block scope have exactly ?

Comment: `doSmth` function and `age` both are in same block so the age variable still with in the scope.

Comment: `doSmth` is in the same scope as `age`.

Comment: [see here how code execution](http://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#code=function%20doSmth%28%29%7B%0Aage%3D27%3B%0A%7D%0Alet%20age%3B%0AdoSmth%28%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28age%29%3B&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D)

Comment: @jagad89 - Even if you wrap it in a block, this code will work. It will just create another variable age in global scope.

Comment: I think it's related to `closure`, `doSmth` function has the context environment whose the variable `age` outside.

Comment: @Vatsal agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Let has block scope" doesn't mean that the variable must be defined in the same block - it means that the level at which the variable is defined *can* be a block.

In contrast, the level at which a `var` variable is defined cannot be a block, unless that block is also a function block. If a `var` variable is initialized inside a non-function block, it will be hoisted out to the nearest outer block which is also a function block.

No matter whether a variable is declared with `var`, `let`, or `const`, it will be referencable anywhere else inside the same block in which it was declared, including inside child blocks. (For `let` and `const`, the line that declares the variable, eg `const foo =`, must also have run for a reference to `foo` to work without throwing.)

Another way of looking at it is: if a variable is referenced somewhere, the interpreter looks for whether it's initialized in the *current* block. If so, that's the binding that's used. Otherwise, it looks in the *next outer* block to see if the variable is initialized there - if so, *that's* the binding that's used. And so on. If it gets all the way to the top level, and no binding has been found, and it's not a property of the global object, that reference will throw a `ReferenceError`.

In your code, the `age` variable happens to be global, since it's defined on the top level, but that doesn't really matter - the code would work the same if `age` was just an an *outer* block, but not on the top level, eg:

```js
function foo() {
  function doSmth() {
    age = 27;
  }
  let age;
  doSmth();
  console.log(age);
}

foo();
```

Comment: Your third paragraph is not entirely true.  You can't reference a `let` or `const` variable in the block BEFORE it's definition.

Comment: Is the comment mentioned above by @jfriend00 true ?

Comment: @testndtv Yes - see *(For let and const, the line that initializes the variable, eg `const foo =`, must also have run for a reference to foo to work without throwing.)*

Comment: Also, to understand this further, one must keep in mind that scope chain is still applicable and behaves similar for "let" as it does for "var"...as in the above example, there is scope chain/lexical scoping also coming into play which is why we get the age as 27 (i.e. parent/containing scope reference value)


Would that be correct ?

Comment: @testndtv Yes, and it would work exactly the same if `age` was declared with `var` instead.

Comment: Would you want to correct this statement to "declares the variable" instead of "initializes the variable" ?

"For let and const, the line that initializes the variable, eg const foo =, must also have run for a reference to foo to work without throwing."

Answer (score 1):

> Now I am a bit confused as to how this works. Specifically, I have read is that `let` has a block scope.

Yes, `let` has block scope.  But a block such as inside your `doSmmth()` function has access to ALL the variables in parent scopes that have been defined or hoisted at the time of the function execution.

So, `let age;` is in the parent scope and has been defined by the time `doSmth()` executes.  Therefore the interpreter tasked with looking up a variable named `age` finds it in the parent scope just fine.

> So, how is it that `let age`, which is declared outside the function `doSmth`, is the same variable inside the function doSmth?

Here's how the interpreter works in this regard.  Your code executes in these steps:

1. Parse the code you've presented.
2. The `function doSmth()` definition is encountered.  Functions are hoisted to the top of the containing function scope so that definition is immediately added to this scope object.  `let age` is also encountered in the parsing and is added to the parsed scope, but it is marked in a way that it will not yet be accessible to code.
3. Start executing the code.  A new scope object is created from the parsed code.
4. `let age;` is encountered.  This marks the `age` variable which was previous put into this scope at parsing time as now available for code to use.
5. Call `doSmth()`.  This pushes a return address on the callstack and as it sets up to execute `doSmth()`, it creates a new function scope.
6. It then executes `age = 27` inside that function.  The interpreter looks in the local scope for a symbol named `age`.  It doesn't find one.  So, it goes up the scope chain and looks in the parent scope.  It finds a matching symbol and uses that one.
7. The function returns which pops a return address off the call stack and resets the current scope back to the parent scope and the execution goes to right after where `doSmth()` was and executes the `console.log(age)`.
8. The interpreter looks in the local scope for a symbol named `age` and finds it and uses it.

So, the main keys here that it sounds like you may be confused by are:

1. If a symbol isn't found in the local scope, then the parent scopes are searched for the symbol name.
2. `let` does create a block-scoped symbol, but it can still be accessed by any child functions also declared in that scope.
3. In this particular code, there wouldn't be any difference between `let` and `var` and it isn't hoisting that makes this work.  It's parent scopes.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, both doSmth and age are in global scope. Windows for browser and module object for node. So they basically are in the same scope.

Comment: That's not the global scope in node.js.  It might be module scope.  You can't write code in the global scope in node.js.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will go through two phases.

1. Compilation where all hoisting will occur (var declared variables).
2. Execution where actual execution of code will occur.

In first phase you will declare function `doSmith` and `age` variable. Before executeion phase JS engine knows what is `age` variable and what is `doSmith`.

In next phase i.e. execution phase, execution will occur,

```
doSmth();
console.log(age);
```

will get executed. Hence in age variable is accessible to function `doSmith` in execution phase.

Comment: @Vatsal Yes same book